# Define a dynamic not_analyzed field for a nested document

Tags: dynamic, mapping, elasticsearch

I have a document like below, the "tags" field is a nested document, and I want to make all child field for tags document to be index = not_analyzed. The problem is that field in tags will be dynamic. any tag could possible.
So how I can define dynamic mapping for this.

```
{
 strong text'level': 'info',
 'tags': {
  'content': u'Nov  6 11:07:10 ja10 Keepalived_healthcheckers: Adding service [172.16.08.105:80] to VS [172.16.1.21:80]',
  'id': 1755360087,
  'kid': '2012121316',
  'mailto': 'yanping3,chunying,pengjie',
  'route': 15,
  'service': 'LVS',
  'subject': 'LVS_RS',
  'upgrade': 'no upgrade configuration for this alert'
 },
 'timestamp': 1383707282.500464
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use [dynamic templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_templates) for this. For example following shell script creates `dynamic_mapping_test` index with `dynamic template` set when indexing field `tags.*`, mapping is set to `type:string` and `index:not_analyzed`.

```
echo "Delete dynamic_mapping_test"
curl -s -X DELETE http://localhost:9200/dynamic_mapping_test?pretty ; echo ""

echo "Create dynamic_mapping_test with nested tags and dynamic_template"
curl -s -X POST http://localhost:9200/dynamic_mapping_test?pretty -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_template": {
            "path_match": "tags.*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}' ; echo ""


echo "Display mapping"
curl -s "http://localhost:9200/dynamic_mapping_test/_mapping?pretty" ; echo ""

echo "Index document with new property tags.content"
curl -s -X POST "http://localhost:9200/dynamic_mapping_test/document?pretty" -d '{
  "tags": {
    "content": "this CONTENT should not be analyzed"
  }
}' ; echo ""

echo "Refresh index"
curl -s -X POST "http://localhost:9200/dynamic_mapping_test/_refresh"

echo "Display mapping again"
curl -s "http://localhost:9200/dynamic_mapping_test/_mapping?pretty" ; echo ""

echo "Index document with new property tags.title"
curl -s -X POST "http://localhost:9200/dynamic_mapping_test/document?pretty" -d '{
  "tags": {
    "title": "this TITLE should not be analyzed"
  }
}' ; echo ""

echo "Refresh index"
curl -s -X POST "http://localhost:9200/dynamic_mapping_test/_refresh"; echo ""

echo "Display mapping again"
curl -s "http://localhost:9200/dynamic_mapping_test/_mapping?pretty" ; echo ""
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, all string "not_analyzed", and all numbers to long and "not_analyzed".

Because default string analyzed have more memory and file size.

I have reduced size and search fields' full word

range search long type.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "_type": {
        "index": "no",
        "store": false
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "el": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "long",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "long",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "es": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need the `"el"` dynamic template. `"index": "not_analyzed"` [is used by default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38080488/325852). You might [use it though](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-mapping-type) if you want to change the type from `long` to `integer` as an optimisations step

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to specify mapping while indexing the data. So, as an alternative, you can modify your tags document to have the following mapping:

```
{ tags: {
          properties: {
                        tag_type: {type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'}
                        tag_value: {type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'}
                       }
        }
}
```

Here, `tag_type` can contain the any of the values (`content`, `id`, `kid`, `mailto`, etc.), and `tag_values` can contain the actual value of the field that is named in tag_type.

Comment: I think it is possible with [dynamic templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_templates)

Comment: Thnx, I din know that..:)