# Are numbers: integer, long, float etc... in Elasticsearch not_analyzed?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch 1.4.3

I went through the docs but I'm not sure exactly. But I figure that integer, long, float, double etc... are indexed as not_analyzed by Lucene right?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From this [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) you have this statement:

> The other simple types (such as `long`, `double`, `date` etc) also accept the index parameter, but the only relevant values are `no` and `not_analyzed`, as their values are never analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, non-string types (such as long, double, date etc) are **not analyzed** by default.

That's why you can omit `"index": "not_analyzed"` in the following mapping definition:

```
...
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "price": {
            "type": "long",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
...
```

But you might decide to not index this field at all:

```
...
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "price": {
            "type": "long",
            "index": "no"
        }
    }
}
...
```

As a result this field will not be searchable.

Find the resource [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2)